# Doctrine 2, how to add custom attribute to array result rows?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have this code:

```
$contents = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM SomeClass\\Terminal p WHERE p.user = 1)->getResult();
$response = new Response(json_encode($contents));
```

I want to add more attributes to the objects inside of $contents **without adding new columns to my table**, I can't find a way to add custom properties to the doctrine objects. I just want to add some extra attributes every time I convert these objects to arrays.

Thanks.

Comment: You can add fields to your entity without mapping them to the database  so they won't be persisted

Comment: Hey Ko2r, I tried this, but they don't appear through the getResult method.

Comment: I've missunderstood the question :) it's not possible to add extra field, to your entity, not stored in the database and be able to retrieve the whole entity with the unsaved field ! You can add an attribute unsaved and compute it when you retrieve the entity but I don't know if it's fitting your problem ... what king of attribute do you want to add ?

Comment: It's an attribute calculated with a business rule. For example a concatenation between attribute A and B (something more complicated in my case).

Comment: Well in this case you can do this, just add the field (getter and setter too) and when you retrieve your entity just compute the value, set the field and put in into response